# Django rest framework, seriialize multiple fields at once

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose you want to include 5 images and the total image count for your restaurant when you serialize a restaurant.

You can query DB for each field in separate method, 
but it would be beneficial to work in one method to utilize a QuerySet.

Is there a way to serialize multiple fields at once in DRF?

Answer (score 0):

If all of these fall under one model then building a simple model serializer will account for them all. Take for instance:

```
# Model
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    @property
    def image_count(self):
        queryset = apps.get_model('app_label', 'Image')
        count = queryset.objects.filter(restaurant=self).count()
        return count

class Image(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name="image_set")
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Serializers.py

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ['image_count', ]
```

@ Property allows something as such to be serialized, the method could also just use the related name.

If you want to further serialize the Image object you must read http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/